# Creating Notebooks, Sections and Pages in OneNote with Powershell..beginner's perspective

Tags: powershell

Apologies, a fairly broad request eith little to offer.  I would like to be able to create sections and page in onenote from a list, say in excel, using Powershell.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. What you are really asking is for someone to do your googling for you. I suggest that you do some research on the general topic then start writing your script(s). Then if you have specific problems post a question here to help you overcome that specific hurdle.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is still current enough to work properly without knowing what version of Powershell you are running, but here are a few pages that could help you out.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/jamesone/archive/2007/10/02/powershell-and-one-note-no-really.aspx

http://bdewey.com/2007/07/18/onenote-powershell-provider/

Essentially this gives you a OneNote provider that would let you navigate and create One-Note notebooks and pages as you would with any other powershell provider. Could help you out with what you are doing.